# show web page in web browser using phantomJS

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

Is it possible to show page in web browser (for example in Chrome or Firefox) using phantomJS? I mean, I go on web site, fill in login and password fields and click OK button. After that new page is loading. I want to show this new page in web browser. Is it possible to do with phantomJS? If yes - please, tell me how to do it. If no - please, tell me what should I try to use (I need in hidden mode do some things on web pages (fill in forms, click buttons) and finally show the result in web browser).
I'll appreciate any help.

Comment: why don't you use something like selenium to control chrome/firefox first?

Comment: @Daniel A. White it shows browser from the very beginning (for example, in C#, it'll shows at that line: `IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`). And I need first do things in hidden mode and only then show browser's window.